# Is there a way to make my nodejs - selenium macro store cache?

Tags: node.js, selenium, macros

I'm trying to build a macro that opens the browser, goes to my outlook account, exports my planner to excel and saves in the same folder.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    await driver.get('https://path to my outlook-planner account.com');
})();
```

But, every time i run the application the chromedrive.exe open without cache, and asks me again to loggin into the account again.
Is there a way to already stay logged-in in my account ?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the browser with a specific user instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```